# Does CVE-2015-5352 work if there is no active X-Server?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

My security program shows that [one of my servers](https://thejh.net/written-stuff/openssh-6.8-xsecurity) is vulnerable to [CVE-2015-5352](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-5352).  If X-Server is not running (not even installed) is the system really penetrable by that vulnerability?

Answer (score 2):

To understand this vulnerability you need to understand the way how the X11 forwarding over ssh works and what part is vulnerable. There is basic image:

```
[  ssh client  ] --> [  ssh server  ]  
 [ x11 server ]       [ x11 client ]
```

The one who is vulnerable is the part with ssh-client and x11 server if connecting to malicious ssh server. If there is no X-server on client, there is nothing to exploit.

Answer (score 1):

> If X-Server is not running (not even installed) is the system really
>   penetrable by that vulnerability?

In that case you simply need to [disable](https://www.google.fi/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=x11%20forwarding&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZFvoVe_fG4zFYLO1gaAK#channel=fs&q=disable%20x11%20forwarding) X11 forwarding in OpenSSH.